# Javscript function to post form data that contains HTML input array

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form that contains an input array such that

```
<input type="text" name="title[]"/>
<input type="text" name="title[]"/>
<input type="text" name="title[]"/>
```

I am trying to post this data via a post fetch method. But the data on the form for the above inputs is empty when I try to get the form values. Is there a way to easily do this without having to loop through each of the elements and get the values from the array then append to the form data before posting?

Answer (score 0):

Pass a [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) as the body of the request (do **not** manually set a `Content-Type` header).

Construct the object by passing the form to it.

```
const body = new FormData(document.querySelector("form");
```

NB: This will create a multipart/form-data formatted request. Make sure your server-side code can handle it. Most will automatically. Node.js based servers will typically need careful select of body parsing modules.